# Make 2 Links Appear Selected at the Same Time

Tags: html, css

so I have 2 links that both link to the same thing and are even just on separate lines. However, because of the formatting I use for links, I had to break it in two. Now it just looks wonky when you hover on one and it doesn't highlight the other... So if there's a way to make the other "selected" (or well, hovered on), could you share?

Here's my code:

(I'm aware that the link colour has garbage contrast with its background. I'm going to fix it later once I have this all fixed up. I'm also aware that clicking the link gives an error. I didn't add in the JavaScript for them)

```css
.linko {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
  height: 41px;
  width: 65px;
  margin: 2px 0px 2px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #69A373;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #3C654D;
  color: #3C654D;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
  color: #163A29;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover:before,
a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #163A29;
}
```

```html
<div class="linko">
  <a style="position:relative;top:4px;display:inline-block;" href="javaScript:void(0);" onClick="load_alerts();">Alerts</a>
  <br />
  <a style="position:relative;display:inline-block; margin-top:5px;" href="javaScript:void(0);" onClick="load_alerts();">(2)</a>
  <div style="display:none;" id="recent-alerts">
    <div class="tableborder">
      <div class="pformstrip">Recent Alerts
        <div style="float: right;"><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('recent-alerts').style.display='none';void(0);">[x]</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <span id="recent-alerts-data"></span>
      <div style="text-align: center;" class="pformstrip">
        <a title="View All Alerts" href="http://pjonline.tk/index.php?act=UserCP&amp;CODE=alerts">View All Alerts</a> · <a title="Mark All Read" href="javascript:read_alerts();">Mark All Read</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just create a new class, use a jquery onhover to affect the class of both?

Comment: a) The layout of the forum's HTML makes that hard
b) I have no idea how to make that
c) Anything Javascript/JQuery loads slow on the forum. I try to arrange things without using it.

Comment: You do realize you are using js in your posted code...

Comment: I didn't make it. I just copy/pasted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated on request:** This is using exact code from OP and applying addClass to multiple `<a>` links with pseudo elements onHover with jquery.

https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/cz8st2fv/

You can use a addClass to effect the links in many ways. 
Here is a sample using background on all 'a' links.

https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/9gru7Lmx/

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $('a').addClass('active');
},function(){
    $('a').removeClass('active');
});
```

If you want to add pseudo classes there is a different approach. Simply create a new class in this case I created a.someclass and addClass on hover with jquery. Look at the last line of your css and the jquery to see what I have done. It in turn attaches to 'a'.

CSS

```
a:hover:before,
a:hover:after, a.someclass{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #163A29;
}
```

Jquery

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $('a').addClass('someclass');
},function(){
    $('a').removeClass('someclass');
});
```

[Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/d5djstfy/)

Comment: This doesn't quite do it, though ^^; The other link wont appear hovered on; It keeps at having just a dotted bottom border.

Comment: then simply add that affect to the class. In the class I added, it only adds a background, you can style it as you wish.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to add the borders to the other text line...? Would you know how?

Comment: As in your a:before and a:after?

Comment: Yes, those two. They're what my links are when hovered on.

Comment: Passing pseudo elements is a little trickier and we should possibly thin out the amount of classes for that.. are you ok with this?

Comment: If that's what we have to do, I'm willing. Just, how do we do it? @norcaljohnny

Comment: Give me a few and I will show some code.. Can you elaborate a little more on why the links can not simply have a <br> in the middle opposed to a  new div?

Comment: Err... They do? I'm talking about the `href`s. Y'know, `<a style="position:relative;top:4px;display:inline-block;" href="javaScript:void(0);" onClick="load_alerts();">Alerts</a>
  <br />
  <a style="position:relative;display:inline-block; margin-top:5px;" href="javaScript:void(0);" onClick="load_alerts();">(2)</a>` <-- that.

Comment: Ye. My only gripe about it now is that it makes the lines really tall and span across the entire thing as opposed to just lining over the text like it normally should...

Comment: @Foxwells look at the top of my answer with new jsfiddle.

Comment: Whoa! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127462/discussion-between-foxwells-and-norcal-johnny).